# fibonacci sequence sum total error

Tags: c++, fibonacci

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int last;

do{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"                              FIBONACCI                         "<<endl;
    int a,sum;
    cout<<"Enter the number of outputs you want to be displayed : ";
    cin>>a;

    long long unsigned int b= 0, c=1;
    while(a >=0)
    {
            cout<<b<<endl;
            sum+=b;
            b=b+c;
            c=b-c;
            a--;                        
    }
    cout<<"total = "<<sum<<endl;
    cin>>last;
}
while(last==0);

system("pause");
return 0;   
}
```

whenever i want to repeat it by giving 0 as the last input the value of sum doesn't reset itself and the new sum gets added to the previous one and a wrong value is displayed as the total.

Comment: It might help if you add a language tag...

Comment: Tip: code is more legible with more spaces: `b = b + c;`

Comment: @Satwik : if one of the answer helped you to fix your code, don't forget to accept it ;)

Answer (score 3):

your variable sum is not initialized before you access it.

You should change

```
int a,sum;
```

to

```
int a;
int sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `sum` incorrectly it should be the same type as `b` and `c`

```
long long unsigned int sum;
```

and `sum` was uninitialised too, but: your calculation is very strange

```
sum+=b;
b=b+c;
c=b-c;
```

So I recommend

```
sum = c + b;
b = c;
c = sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int last;

do{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"FIBONACCI \n\n";      
    int a,sum;
    cout<<"Enter the number of outputs you want to be displayed : ";
    cin>>a;

    long long unsigned int sum=0,b=0,c=1,d=0;
    while(a >=0)
    {
            cout<<b<<endl;
            sum+=b;
            b=d+c;
            c=d;
            d=b;
            a--;                        
    }
    cout<<"total = "<<sum<<endl;
    cin>>last;
}
while(last==0);

system("pause");
return 0;   
}
```

the change was made in calculation and sum is initialised to zero in beg of the do..while loop and sorry for bad punctuation